# Base template inheritance members, reduce typing needed

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have an issue that is already known in the community (one of the most complete answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24158601/1162884)), but I would like to know if there is a way to make compiler understand that you want to access base template members without needing to use `typedef` or `this` as below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Base{
  T a;
  T a2;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Derived : Base<T2>{
  T2 b;

  void member_fnc();
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Derived<T1,T2>::member_fnc(){
  typedef Base<T2> base;
  std::cout << "a = " << base::a << std::endl;    // or this->a;
  std::cout << "a2 = " << base::a2 << std::endl;  // or this->a2;                     
  std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}

int main(){

  Derived<int,double> der1;
  der1.a = 1;
  der1.a2 = 2;
  der1.b = 1.1;
  der1.member_fnc();

}
```

I have this feeling that there should be a way to say compiler you want to access base template `Base<T2>` without having to type it or including `using` for every member you want to access, as you can unnest namespaces using `using` keyword, but I couldn't find so far. Is it possible, at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Derived : Base<T2>{
  typedef Base<T2> base;
  using base::a;
  using base::a2;

  T2 b;
  void member_fnc();
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Derived<T1,T2>::member_fnc(){
  std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;    // or this->a;
  std::cout << "a2 = " << a2 << std::endl;  // or this->a2;                     
  std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, this just moves typedef to class scope. But i would like to do not need writing `base::` or `this` as we do on non template base classes... I think I am asking too much, aint I?

Comment: @Werner I changed the answer. You still need a little `base::` in the using statements.

Comment: Ok… it seems that it is the best we can get x)