# Overloaded operator= to switch between template types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading, class-template

I have a template class that multiple classes are inheriting from to basically make some user-friendly builders, hiding the functions that are not required on different builders, while following DRY.

However, I'm having trouble switching between the builder types. I'd prefer to use the `operator=` to switch without hassle and have the following code.

```
template<class T> class BuilderFunctions
{
protected:
    std::string text;

public:
    template<class Other>
    BuilderFunctions<T>& operator=(const Other& other);
};

template <class T>
template <class Other>
BuilderFunctions<T>& BuilderFunctions<T>::operator=(const Other& other)
{
    // yes, I need same object protection
    text = other.text;
    return *this;
}
```

Classes

```
class BuilderGenericList : public BuilderFunctions<BuilderGenericList> 
{
public:
    BuilderGenericList() = default;
};

// Build configuration details
class BuilderRootList : public BuilderFunctions<BuilderRootList>
{
private:
    // I'll delete the functions I don't want accessed here

public:
    BuilderRootList() = default;
};
```

Code that says no

```
// Real world you'd build the root first and switch out to another builder or be using a prototype to seed another builder
BuilderRootList cmakeRoot;
BuilderGenericList list;

// Separate to make sure it's not trying to use cop constructor
list = cmakeRoot;
```

Except I might be doing something I shouldn't be doing with template classes, although others seem to have success with templates in the operators, so assume possible, and I'm making some kind of mistake.

---

More info: The error I get is:

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand 
of type 'BuilderRootList' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

So It's definitely looking for my `operator=`, it's just not generating one from the template

Comment: `BuilderFunctions<T1>` cannot access private/protected member of `BuilderFunctions<T2>` (with T1 != T2): add accessor, or make them `friend`.

Comment: `list = cmakeRoot` is trying to call compiler-generated copy-assignment operator `BuilderGenericList& BuilderGenericList::operator=(const BuilderGenericList&)`, instead of the one you defined in `BuilderFunctions`

Comment: @Jarod42 Valid point, gave it a try, but no luck. The error I get is C2679 No matching function to the types. So it's more a signature problem at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the template inheritance, you have to be explicit in case of base classes members. More read:

- [Why do I have to access template base class members through the this pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer)
- [Derived template-class access to base-class member-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120833/derived-template-class-access-to-base-class-member-data)
- [Accessing base member functions in class derived from template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158209/accessing-base-member-functions-in-class-derived-from-template-class)

In your case, the members `text`, and `operator=`, can be brought via `using` declaration.

```
class BuilderGenericList : public BuilderFunctions<BuilderGenericList> 
{
public:
    BuilderGenericList() = default;
    using BuilderFunctions<BuilderGenericList>::text;
    using BuilderFunctions<BuilderGenericList>::operator=;
    // ... so on, other members from base if needed!
};

// Build configuration details
class BuilderRootList : public BuilderFunctions<BuilderRootList>
{
public:
    BuilderRootList() = default;
    using BuilderFunctions<BuilderRootList>::text;
    using BuilderFunctions<BuilderRootList>::operator=;
    // ... so on, other members from base if needed!
};
```

[Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GoEvrhbor)

Note that, this will make the member`using BuilderFunctions<BuilderGenericList>::text` public, if this is not what wanted, consider the suggestion by *@Jarod42* in other answer.

Comment: Uh that did that trick! Thank you

So all template members and operators need this? Any others?

Comment: @Justin Yes,... I have added extended posts to this topic in the answer.

Comment: Your `using BuilderFunctions<BuilderGenericList>::text;` make the field `public`... The field was already accessible (base is not template dependnant)...

Comment: @Jarod42 I see that, but forgot to mention. Since OP accepted that change, I assume he can adapt the change. Otherwise, they have to make the operator friend, as you suggested. ... I have mentioned anyway in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`BuilderFunctions<T1>` cannot access `private`/`protected` member of `BuilderFunctions<T2>` (with `T1` != `T2`): add accessor, or make them `friend`.

in addition, you also have to put using for `operator=`:

```
template<class T>
class BuilderFunctions
{
    template <typename U> friend class BuilderFunctions;
protected:
    std::string text;

public:
    template<class Other>
    BuilderFunctions<T>& operator=(const Other& other);
};

template <class T>
template <class Other>
BuilderFunctions<T>& BuilderFunctions<T>::operator=(const Other& other)
{
    //yes, I need same object protection
    text= other.text;
    return *this;
}


class BuilderGenericList : public BuilderFunctions<int>{
public:
    using BuilderFunctions<int>::operator=;

    BuilderGenericList() = default;
};

//Build configuration details
class BuilderRootList : public BuilderFunctions<float>
{
private:
//I'll delete the functions I don't want accessed here

public:
    using BuilderFunctions<float>::operator=;

    BuilderRootList() = default;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jsM4bhj54)

Comment: That's a cool way to deal with the friend class. I hadn't realized I'd made the members public, but makes sense.